# How do I show data in Angular?

Tags: angular, fetch

i'm trying to show data in my componenet and it's not working. My web services are working fine , I'm working in flask as backend. i can see the data in my console(network ) but when i try to show it it's undefined. here this is my code:
this is my service:

```
getFolders(): Observable<Dossier[]>
{
    return this._httpClient.get<Dossier[]>(this.baseUrl + 'dossiers');}
```

and this is my component:

```
folders: Dossier;
folder: Dossier;
folderList: Dossier[]= [];
filterLoaded = false;

ngOnInit(): void {
        //folders
        this._fileManagerService.getFolders()
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.folderList = data.Folders;
        this.filterLoaded = true;
        this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
        console.log('folders '+JSON.stringify(this.folderList));
        console.log(this.folderList);
        console.log('data',data);
        });

        // Get the folder
    this._fileManagerService.folder$
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
    .subscribe((folder: Dossier) => {
        this.selecteddItem = folder;

        // Mark for check
        this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    });

    // Subscribe to media query change
    this._fuseMediaWatcherService.onMediaQueryChange$('(min-width: 1440px)')
        .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
        .subscribe((state) => {

            this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
        });
}
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<!-- Folders -->
<div> {{ this.filterLoaded }}
    <div class="font-medium">Folders</div>dddd {{ this.folderList }}vf
    <div class="flex flex-wrap -m-2 mt-2" *ngIf="this.filterLoaded === true">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let folder of this.folderList">

            <div class="aspect-w-9 aspect-h-6">

            <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
                        NAME: {{ folder.name }}
                    </div>
                </div>


        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

as you can see in my console it says undefined
[image]

in my network I got my data : look
[image]

oh and this is my model:

```
export interface Dossier {
idD?: string;
name?: string;
idChild?: string;}
```

if you have an idea please help!

Comment: Have you tried removing the 'this.' in this line:

*ngIf="this.filterLoaded === true" becomes *ngIf="filterLoaded"

Comment: You are doing `data.Folders` and I don't see a field called `Folders` on that JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
this.folderList = data.Folders;
```

use

```
this.folderList = data.dossiers;
```

You are receiving data but you accessing it using wrong key

Comment: yes you're right!

Comment: it worked thak you everyone